# Referenced Library Not Recognized when compiled

Tags: visual-studio, build, reference, visual-studio-2013, class-library

I have created a simple Console application.  I moved all my class files into a separate project because it is shared between this and a Asp.Net MVC application.  I add the library fine.  I add a reference to the project just fine.  Everything looks good until it compiles, then it suddenly can't find the referenced namespace of the project.  If I remove the using statement and add it back in the auto complete works fine and sees the project.  It's only when building that it gives an error.

[image]

Comment: BTW, you forgot to include the most important piece of info...the error you are getting. It might help to know what's the error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight it looks like you're not doing anything wrong. In the past, I've had issues similar to this and the main causes were...

1. Both projects are targeting a different version of the .NET Framework. It can easily be changed from the project's Properties page
2. There are compilation errors on the referenced assembly (class library in this case)
3. The referenced assembly has some missing dependencies. It could be some like a reference to the `System.Web` assembly or `System.Web.MVC`, etc

Comment: It was the framework version.  That has been causing me grief for so long, you have no idea.

Comment: Well, I do that all the time when I'm working in a solution that runs in an earlier version of the .NET Framework other than the latest one. I add a new Project and unconsciously forget to specify a different version in the New Project dialog. It's happened to me so many times that when I get these kinds of errors is the first thing I check...that's why it was the first option in the possible causes list ;)